# Javascript: Issue with window.print

Tags: javascript

In recent update of browsers, (firefox 95+) Something weired happened.

Scenario:

```
- user clicks the print button in main page
- user will be redirected to a new page (print page)
- when the page fully loaded, the window.print() function executes
- when the print dialog dismissed, user will be redirected to main page
```

So for example, I wrote this html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
test
<script language="javascript">
    window.print();
    console.log('1');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

As [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print) describes, The  `window.print()` method will block while the print dialog is open. And its true. unless you have more script lines after that.

Opened an issue [here](https://github.com/mdn/content/issues/11133) and yet, the problem seems unsolved to me.

if you paste

```js
window.print();
console.log('1');
```

directly into browser console, it works as it intended.

Any advise?

Comment: I don't understand, what's the question?

Comment: The page you linked to explains: **If the document is still loading when this function is called, then the document will finish loading before opening the print dialog.** That means that `window.print()` runs asynchronously and the rest of the script executes.

Comment: @Barmar tried my best to describe. The question is "How can i run something AFTER window.print()" and by after, i mean when the print dialog is dismissed

Comment: It also links to window.onafterprint, which further implies async.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onafterprint

Comment: Why would you use `window.print()` while the page is loading in the first place?

Comment: @danh yeah. tried that way too. same behavior.

Comment: @BehzadSafamanesh - my suggestion runs in the snippet editor. Is that not the behavior you're after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me in current Safari and Chrome. The console log is executed after the print dialog is dismissed.

```js
window.onafterprint = event => {
  console.log('after print');
};
window.print();
```

Comment: Thanks. but its not working. as you see, then "after print" is printed before you dismiss the print dialog.

Comment: Browser issue maybe?  It works for me in current Safari (15.1) and somewhat current Chrome (97.0.4692.71). In both, for me, no console log until after the print dialog is dismissed.

Comment: You are right. My own code was buggy in FF and chrome. but your code seems ok in chrome. Shall i report it in FF community?